# SharedPreferences not storing data and returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using an class in my application which, to create a session so that i can store an move vars between activities etc. So i have a certain class that uses `SharedPrefrences` to do that.

I do also have a google map with an overlay and items on it. My purpose is to be able to store some geolocation information, when an `onTap` event happens.

For this purpose, i created a second void in my `SessionManager` class (which uses SharedPrefrences), which i call inside the `onTap` event. The problem is that i faced a `NullPointerException`. The vars inside the void are collected properly from the map and are not null. This is inside the onTap event:

```
GeoPoint mPoint;
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  mPoint = item.getPoint();

session.mapInputs(Double.toString(mPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1E6), Double.toString(mPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
```

When i call `mapInputs()` faced the `NullPointerException`. I am not sure what all the reasons are for getting a `NullPointerException`, Double checked the variables passed in a void, they are not empty. I also tried to create a new class with `SharedPrefrences`, but the same problem appears again.

So i can't figure out what i am doing wrong..

Here are my Logcat errors(Line 60 in MapFeeder is the mapInputs void):

```
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at        com.cabman.lol.ok.MapFeeder.onTap(MapFeeder.java:60)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at  com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:347)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:647)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-04 15:47:37.999: E/AndroidRuntime(308):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is also a part of my SessionManger class:

```
public class SessionManager {


SharedPreferences pref;

Editor editor;

Context context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
```

....

```
 public SessionManager(Context context){

    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

....

```
    public void mapInputs(String startLat,  String startLon ){

editor.putString(KEY_LAT, startLat);
editor.putString(KEY_LON, startLon);
editor.commit();
```

}

Comment: Post your LogCat errors, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Ok, if line 60 is where you call `mapInputs()` either `session` or `mPoints` is null. You can use your debugger to figure out which one is the culprit.

Comment: mPoint is surely not null as i have printed.The problem must be in session,as i have also tried to pass string characters and it still returns null. The problem is that i use the mapInputs exactly the same way i use a different void in the same class for storing data.. so i can not understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: where do you instantiate "session"?

Comment: At the beginning of the class like that: SessionManager session;

Comment: In my SessionManager class, as i mentioned before i have another void for storing different data, could it be that i am not aloud to do that?